# in python why if rank: is faster than if rank != 0:

Tags: python, performance, numpy

When I changed

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    rank = ranks[i]
    if rank != 0:
        pass
```

to:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    rank = ranks[i]
    if rank:
        pass
```

I found the second code is much more efficient, why?

bench mark it, and in my situation ranks is an numpy array of integer. The difference is much more.

```
import numpy as np
import time
N = 1000000
ranks = np.random.random_integers(0, 10, N)
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, N):
    rank = ranks[i]
    if rank != 0:
        pass

print time.time() - start
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, N):
    rank = ranks[i]
    if rank:
        pass
print time.time() - start
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, N):
    if i != 0:
        pass

print time.time() - start
start = time.time()
for i in range(0, N):
    if i:
        pass
print time.time() - start
```

output:

```
1.15917396545
0.45020198822
0.123136997223
0.122531175613
```

Comment: I'd expect a bit of a boost, since less of the work happens in interpreted Python and more of it happens in built-in methods, but in a real program, it probably wouldn't be big. (It's still worth doing, since it's standard style and less code.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Distilling the checks to the core

```
for i in range(0,100):
  if i != 0:
    pass
```

and

```
for i in range(0,100):
  if i:
    pass
```

We see there is a difference

```
$ python -m timeit 'for i in range(0,100):' ' if i != 0:' '  pass'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.69 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'for i in range(0,100):' ' if i:' '  pass'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.18 usec per loop
```

The difference is that while the first case involves comparing to zero, the second case just tests if false.

To see what it is doing, use [dis](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis):

```
>>> def f():
...  for i in range(0,100):
...    if i:
...      pass
...
>>> def g():
...  for i in range(0,100):
...    if i != 0:
...      pass
...
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              32 (to 35)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                15 (to 34)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             25 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  4          28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   34 POP_BLOCK
        >>   35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis(g)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              38 (to 41)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             15 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                21 (to 40)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             25 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)   <-- this only happens in != 0
             28 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)  <-- this only happens in != 0
             31 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16

  4          34 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
             37 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   40 POP_BLOCK
        >>   41 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             44 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I my situation, ranks is an integer array of numpy. It seems that the difference is much more.

Comment: If you `dis` both samples, the difference is still `LOAD_CONST 1 (0)` and `COMPARE_OP 3 (!=)`.

Comment: but, how to explain if you replace that `if` with `i == True`? the latter is even slower

Comment: @sza quite simply, `True` is a global, so python performs the operation `LOAD_GLOBAL` as opposed to `LOAD_CONST`

Comment: `True` is a built-in variable. Python has to perform two dict lookups (one in the globals dict, one in the builtins) just to figure out what `True` is. In Python 3, this is no longer the case.

Comment: In Py2k you can do `True,False = False,True`, which makes `False == not True`, but `False` is now `True` and `True` is now `False`.

Comment: I just repeated the `timeit` tests on Windows with Python 3.8.6 and got a consistent 13.1 nsec for both cases.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think that may be to do with how timeit is being used. If I do ```%timeit 'for i in range(0,100):' ' if i != 0:' '  pass'``` and equivalently for the other case, I get the same times(```8.2 ns```), but if I put the two codes in a function and time the function, I get ```3.11 µs ± 12.8 ns``` for the ```if != 0``` case and ```2.15 µs ± 5.64 ns``` for the ```if i``` case. Using Python 3.8.13 and macOS

Comment: @MarkRansom actually, I think you're just timing creating a string. I get ```7.89 ns``` for both ```%timeit 'for i in range(0,100):' ' if i != 0:' '  pass'``` and ```%timeit 'a'``` - python 3.10.5