# Recursive function to reduce zeros from number

Tags: python

I have a mission to write a recursive function named Reduce. This function should reduce all the zeros from number and return new number.
for example:
Reduce(-160760) => -1676
Reduce(1020034000) => 1234
I started to to something but I got stuck in the condition. here's the code I wrote so far:

```
def Reduce(num):
    while num != 0:
        if num % 10 != 0:
            newNum = (num % 10) + 


    Reduce(num//10)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post all of your code, not a screenshot of your code

Comment: That's all the code

Comment: Question - do you really have to solve this in *recursion*?  If there is better faster way, can it be accepted?

Answer (score 3):

```py
def reduce(num):
    if num == 0: return 0
    if num < 0: return -reduce(-num)
    if num % 10 == 0:
        return reduce(num // 10)
    else:
        return num % 10 + 10 * reduce(num // 10)
```

Comment: it's more pythonic (and faster) to use ```if not num:``` and ```if not num % 10:```

Comment: @Nin17 sometimes clear and readable wins out over Pythonic. I think this code is fine as is.

Comment: @MarkRansom well it was just a suggestion, I guess it's up to the user to decide if the performance gains of a few percent (depending on input) are worth the slight loss in readability

Comment: @Nin17 I'm used to C++ which optimizes so that there would be no difference in performance. Not sure how Python works in this case but I wouldn't expect a noticeable performance difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049909/in-python-why-if-rank-is-faster-than-if-rank-0) for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

String version of recursive function:

```py
def reduce(n):
    return int(reduce_recursive(str(n), ''))

def reduce_recursive(num, res): 
    if not num: # if we've recursed on the whole input, nothing left to do
        return res 
    if num[0] == '0': # if the character is '0', ignore it and recurse on the next character
        return reduce_recursive(num[1:], res) 
    return reduce_recursive(num[1:], res+num[0])   # num[0] is not a '0' so we add it to the result and we move to the next character                                                                                                                                                                        

>>> reduce(1200530060)                                                                                                                                                                                 
12536
```

Comment: I thought it was clear from the question that the answer was to be based on numeric operations, not string. There are numerous improvements that could be made if you're willing to relax the constraints in the question.